# SFML Animations behaving weirdly

Tags: c++, sfml

So I have been recently learning SFML, and have been following a very useful tutorial. He uses a sprite sheet where every animation has it's own line, while mine does not do that. For that reason, I had to rework the animation script, and it seems to be causing some issues. I have [text](https://rvros.itch.io/animated-pixel-hero) as my spritesheet.
My player update function is

```
void Player::Update(float deltaTime)
{
    sf::Vector2f movement(0.0f, 0.0f);
    bool running = false;

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::A)) {
        movement.x -= speed * deltaTime;
    }
    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::D)) {
        movement.x += speed * deltaTime;
    }
    if (movement.x == 0.0f) {
        running = false;
    }
    else {
        running = true;

        if (movement.x > 0.0f) {
            faceRight = true;
        }
        else {
            faceRight = false;
        }
    }
    if (running == true) {
        animation.Update(sf::Vector2u(1,1), deltaTime, sf::Vector2u(6,1), faceRight);
    }
    else {
        animation.Update(sf::Vector2u(0, 0), deltaTime, sf::Vector2u(4, 0), faceRight);
    }
    body.setTextureRect(animation.uvRect);
    body.move(movement);
}
```

My code animates by just cycling through the animation and taking in starting square and ending square, which is as follows

```
void Animation::Update(sf::Vector2u startingSquare, float deltaTime, sf::Vector2u endingSquare, bool faceRight) {
    totalTime += deltaTime;

    if (totalTime >= switchTime) {
        totalTime -= switchTime;
        currentImage.x++;
        if (currentImage.x >= endingSquare.x && currentImage.y == endingSquare.y) {
            currentImage.x = startingSquare.x;
            currentImage.y = startingSquare.y;
        }
        if (currentImage.y >= imageCount.y) {
            currentImage.x = 0;
            currentImage.y = 0;
        }
        if (currentImage.x >= imageCount.x) {
            currentImage.x = 0;
            currentImage.y++;
        }
    }

    if (faceRight) {
        uvRect.left = currentImage.x * uvRect.width;
        uvRect.width = abs(uvRect.width);
    }
    else {
        uvRect.left = (currentImage.x + 1) * abs(uvRect.width);
        uvRect.width = -abs(uvRect.width);
    }
    uvRect.top = currentImage.y * uvRect.height;
}
```

I have tried messing with the starting square and ending square as well as looking for issues in the loop for the Animation script, however no matter what I do it doesn't seem to stop the animation when it is supposed to. While running it also seems to delay the running animation, which worked fine before I had the idle animation (the broken one) I am using Adventurer.zip, not the v1.3 or v1.5
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You keep saying "script", but there are no scripts in sight. C++ is a compiled language, not a scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i tried to solve your problem. The code you've provided isn't enough information to be able to replicate the problem. The easiest way to solve your problem would be in my opinion to just change the image to a format that for you is easier to understand (each animation is in a new line rather than all bunched together). There is no point in overworking yourself so hard just to write a logical adapter + animation algorithm that would pick and choose the correct animations. Apart from it being more tricky it also comes with the risk of showing the wrong animations or just wrong single animation images or even by going out of bounds possibly.

That being said if you still want to do it this way, maybe a good idea would be insead to divide the image into its portions and save them to a 2 dimentional vector of sf::textures. This would ease your further use and eventual changes to the animation sequences.

General pseudo code for the plan:

```cpp
class NewerAnimationClass
{
public:
    vector<vector<sf::Texture*>> animationTiles;
    int currentAnimationRow;
    int currentAnimationCollumn;

    NewerAnimationClass(string imagePath, sf::Vector2f imageBoundsXY, int imageCount, sf::Vector2f tileSizes) //after image rearange
    {
        //imagePath is the path to the spriteSheet
        //imageBounds are the amount of images in the x and y
        //imagecount is the amount of total images/times in the spritesheet (your sprite sheet doesnt have all tiles filled. last few are empty)
        //tile sizes are the sizes of each tiles

        sf::Image im; //to hold your entire spritesheet
        im.loadFromFile(imagePath); //load it

        for(int i = 0; i < imageBoundsXY.x; i++) //get 2 dim vector ready with empty pointers
        {
            vector<sf::Texture*> tmp;
            animationTiles.emplace_back(tmp);
        }

        for(int y = 0; y < imageBoundsXY.y; y++) //go through spritesheet
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < imageBoundsXY.x; x++)
            {
                if (imageBoundsXY.x*imageBoundsXY.y + imageBoundsXY.x < imageCount) //check if the image we're on is below max amount of images in sprite sheet
                {
                    //if it is then we add it:
                    sf::Texture *tmp = new sf::Texture;
                    tmp->loadFromImage(im, sf::IntRect(x*tileSizes.x, y*tileSizes.y, tileSizes.x, tileSizes.y));
                    animationTiles[y].emplace_back(tmp);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    NewerAnimationClass(string imagePath, sf::Vector2f imageBoundsXY, int imageCount, sf::Vector2f tileSizes, vector<int> startingAnimationPositions) //without image rearange
    {
        //imagePath is the path to the spriteSheet
        //imageBounds are the amount of images in the x and y
        //imagecount is the amount of total images/times in the spritesheet (your sprite sheet doesnt have all tiles filled. last few are empty)
        //tile sizes are the sizes of each tiles
        //startinganimationPositions is a vector with the starting position/number of tiles. eg if animation starts at row y 2 x 2 pos would be y*x*2 + 2. (position in line)

        sf::Image im; //to hold your entire spritesheet
        im.loadFromFile(imagePath); //load it

        for(int i = 0; i < startingAnimationPositions.size(); i++) //get 2 dim vector ready with empty pointers
        {
            vector<sf::Texture*> tmp;
            animationTiles.emplace_back(tmp);
        }

        int min = 0;
        int max = 0;
        int row = 0;
        int current = 0;
        min = max+min;
        max = startingAnimationPositions[row];

        for(int y = 0; y < imageBoundsXY.y; y++) //go through spritesheet
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < imageBoundsXY.x; x++)
            {
                if (imageBoundsXY.x*imageBoundsXY.y + imageBoundsXY.x < imageCount) //check if the image we're on is below max amount of images in sprite sheet
                {
                    if (current > max)
                    {
                        min = max+min;
                        row++;
                        max = startingAnimationPositions[row];
                    }
                    //if it is then we add it:
                    sf::Texture *tmp = new sf::Texture;
                    tmp->loadFromImage(im, sf::IntRect(x*tileSizes.x, y*tileSizes.y, tileSizes.x, tileSizes.y));
                    animationTiles[row].emplace_back(tmp);
                    current++;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int y = 0; y < imageBoundsXY.y; y++) //go through spritesheet
        {
            for(int x = 0; x < imageBoundsXY.x; x++)
            {
                if (imageBoundsXY.x*imageBoundsXY.y + imageBoundsXY.x < imageCount) //check if the image we're on is below max amount of images in sprite sheet
                {
                    //if it is then we add it:
                    sf::Texture *tmp = new sf::Texture;
                    tmp->loadFromImage(im, sf::IntRect(x*tileSizes.x, y*tileSizes.y, tileSizes.x, tileSizes.y));
                    animationTiles[y].emplace_back(tmp);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //then in player:
//    void setAnimation()
//    {

//    }
//    void update(float deltaTime)
//    {
//        //...just switching images in the current vector row
          //example: body.setTexture(&animation.animationTiles[y][x]); where y is the animation type: walk jump run etc. and x is the width i.e. frame by frame of that animation
//    }
};
```

Hope this helps. If there's any inconsistencies let me know